# How can I select the value of a column depending on where the maximum value between a second and third column is, in sql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am a first year student learning SQL. I would like to know how I can select the data_jogo (date_game) value, where a certain player achieved his maximum score, in a match.
This player can appear as player 1 (id_jogador1) or player 2 (id_jogador2).
Table name is "partidas", translating it means matches, and
"pontuacao_jog1" means player 1's score, and "pontuacao_jog2" is the same for player 2.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CmsU1.png)

I tried this way, but doesn't work (#1111 - Uso inválido de função de agrupamento (GROUP)):

```
SELECT partidas.data_jogo AS Date
FROM partidas 
WHERE (partidas.id_jogador1 = 'CR7' OR partidas.id_jogador2 = 'CR7')
AND GREATEST (max (partidas.pontuacao_jog1), max (partidas.pontuacao_jog2));
```

Can someone help please?

Thank you, João

Comment: You haven't thought trough how to get to the data. The syntax error is because you are using `MAX` in the `WHERE` clause. This is not allowed. With `WHERE` you look at original rows not at aggregated data. Then, `GREATEST(val1, val2)` results in a value, lets say 7. Now, what is `WHERE 7` supposed to mean? You want something like `WHERE score = SELECT MAX(score FROM ...)` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `UNION ALL` to get a player's scores in an easy way. Then you can order the scores and use `LIMIT` to get the row with the maximum score:

```
WITH scores AS
(
  SELECT pontuacao_jog1 AS score, data_jogo
  FROM partidas
  WHERE id_jogador1 = 'CR7'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT pontuacao_jog2 AS score, data_jogo
  FROM partidas
  WHERE id_jogador2 = 'CR7'
)
SELECT *
FROM scores
ORDER BY score DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Only problem: If there are two days with the same maximum score, you'll only show one of them arbitrarily chosen. If you want to show both:

```
WITH scores AS ( <same as above> )
SELECT *
FROM scores
WHERE score = (SELECT MAX(score) FROM scores);
```

And here is an alternative way to write the CTE (aka `WITH` clause):

```
WITH scores AS
(
  SELECT
    CASE WHEN id_jogador1 = 'CR7'
      THEN pontuacao_jog1
      ELSE pontuacao_jog2
    END AS score,
    data_jogo
  FROM partidas
  WHERE (id_jogador1 = 'CR7' OR id_jogador2 = 'CR7')
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.
I was trying to use something like "WHERE score = SELECT MAX(score FROM ...)", but as the max value could be in one of the two columns, I didn't have the knowledge to find a solution.
It worked flawlessly. 
The expressions, which you presented and which I didn't know, like "With < > AS", and UNION ALL, I understood how they work and where I can apply them.
Thank you very much.
Kind regards,
João

Comment: That is nice to hear. As you seem so willing to learn, I've added an alternative using a `CASE` expression.

Comment: This structure seems more intuitive. Last year I was learning some C language, which I will continue to study later, and I also used CASE with SWITCH, with different rules.
Thanks again for your help.